# Magento 2 : Add to cart qty validation

Tags: validation, magento2.1.6, qty

[image]

In default Magento 2 Why "e" is allowed to be entered and no any other letters in Qty textbox, It should allow only numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question explain this. It's because "e" can represent a floating number.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706611/why-does-the-html-input-with-type-number-allow-the-letter-e-to-be-entered-in/31706796